# mongodb: Implementing a peculiar unique constraint on optional fields

Tags: mongodb, indexing, unique-constraint

I have a mongodb collection (tags). 
A tag is identified by a "name" field and a "value" field. 
The "value" is optional.

I would like to make the couple ("name", "value") unique, and on top of that, I don't want, for example, the 2 following documents to coexist:

```
{"name": "foo"}
{"name": "foo", "value": "bar"}
```

Creating a unique index **`db.tags.createIndex({name: 1, value: 1}, {unique: true});`** is not enough because it would allow the 2 documents I gave as an example to coexist.

Is there any mongodb feature that would allow me to implement this constraint ? Or do I have to implement it at the application level ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not have a unique index just on the _name_ field?

Comment: I want to allow the 2 following documents to coexist `{"name": "foo", "value": "bar_1"} and {"name": "foo", "value": "bar_2"}`.
But if `{"name": "foo"}` (with no "value" field) exists, then no other document with same "name" should be allowed. I hope I'm being clear ^ ^